# ItemRenderer Doesn't Resize with DataGrid Column

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I have an item renderer tied to an `mx:DataGrid` column. The renderer used to be inline with the column, but I've moved it out to its own file so I can reuse it across multiple tables.

The problem is that now the renderer doesn't resize (grow/shrink) when the column is resized. So if the user makes the column very small, the contents displayed by the renderer just eat up space and show up over top other columns Any ideas how to make this work?

Code for Item Renderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MXDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                          focusEnabled="true">
    <mx:HBox verticalScrollPolicy="auto" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" width="100%">
        <mx:Spacer top="0" bottom="0" width="4" />
        <mx:Image id="typeIcon" buttonMode="false" source="{data.type}" />
    </mx:HBox>
</s:MXDataGridItemRenderer>
```

Code for column using that renderer:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Type" dataField="type" itemRenderer="com.myCompany.myProject.TypeRenderer" />
```

**Edit**

Adding `width=100%` to the `MXDataGridItemRender` didn't work.

Comment: Add `width="100%"` to the `MXDataGridItemRenderer` ?

Comment: I was gonna say what Sam said.  That said, when one column runs beyond it's borders into another; it could be a visual anomoly that no amount of coding seems to fix.  The DataGrid has a lot of these.

Comment: Maybe -- but the old code (that used an inline renderer) worked ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted my question on Adobe's flex forum -- the solution was to remove the outer `s:MXDataGridItemRenderer` and to just let the `mx:HBox` be the root control (no other changes were necessary.)

Strange that he Flex Builder app doesn't give you the option of defining the outermost control, it just plops an `s:MXDataGridItemRenderer` on top...